# Is there simpler, less assuming Craft documentation?

Tags: templating, entries, sections, documentation

I'm really struggling with understanding how Craft works at the moment. 
I've been started mid-way on a particular project and I just can't get my head around how Craft works.

Their documentation seems to assume some knowledge I just don't have and combined with the intermediate-to-expert level of Craft-use in the project I'm on, I just can't figure it out.

Right now I'm failing at even the simplest things. I see fields as 'variables' of an entry, which are then sectioned? 
I'm doing things that work one particular way:

`{% set entries = craft.entries.slug('xyz') %}
{{entries.navigationCaptionTitle}}`

..but not another:

`{% for block in entries %}
  {{ block.navigationCaptionTitle }}
{% endfor %}`

..and I think it's down to my basic understanding of how Sections, Entries and Fields work, how Craft manages them and their basic terminology. I'm definitely a visual learner so anything remotely graphical will help.

I don't have any CMS background, largely just working on html, css and js.

Comment: Check out Mijingos screencast course. This helped me an awfull lot: https://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/up-and-running-with-craft

Comment: As for your example: Have you added a field with the handle "navigationCaptionTitle" to the Matrix block type in question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best is to create fresh Craft instalation and experiment, learn basics. I did the same thing when I was assigned to a large drupal project.

Here is a resource list on Craft:

- http://craftcookbook.net
- http://straightupcraft.com/articles/getting-started-with-craft-cms
- http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/courses/building-landing-pages-with-craft-cms
- http://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries
- https://craftcms.com/support
- http://straightupcraft.com/events/matrix-entry-types-and-advanced-content-layouts

"..and I think it's down to my basic understanding of how Sections, Entries and Fields work"

It's quite simple really :)
You attach fields to section - this defines a "template" for your entry/entries.

Single type section has one entry, Channel & Structure have multiple entries. Also you can create few entry types for Channel & structure (https://straightupcraft.com/articles/how-do-i-output-an-assets-field-inside-a-matrix-field-inside-an-entry-type).

---

**STRUCTURE SECTION EXAMPLE**

1. Create fields
   [image]
2. Create section
   [image]
3. Create Entry types (Click Edit Entry types)
   [image]
   Drag&Drop fields
   [image]
   [image]
4. Create new Entries
   [image]
   Note: Entry type changes
   [image]
   [image]
5. Create entry template file (see step 2 for file location). 
   File located under (installation folder)/craft/templates/example/_entry.twig

[image]

6. Result

[image]
[image]

---

You can also pull those two entries from any twig file like this ([Details](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries)):

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('example') %}
    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{entry.title}}</a><br>
{% endfor %}
```

OR just first one

```
{% set firstExample = craft.entries.section('example').first() %}
<a href="{{ firstExample.url }}">{{firstExample.title}}</a><br>
```

See also [this](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel)

Comment: Your resources are my best bet, and as you said, making a new Craft and following through the whole thing will be best.