# Turning static website to Craft?

Tags: craft-features

I have been working as a freelance web designer now for over 2 years, building websites using plain html, css and jquery.

Most of my clients require simple showcase websites that look well, load fast, well optimised for Google, are easily navigated and show a portfolio of projects. Most also require a blog.

My question is, what is the level of knowledge required in order to take a static html, css website and add Craft CMS to it. The only areas of the website that I would want my clients to have access to would be for them to complete simple tasks such as adding on another project page with an image slider and project details or to add a blog post with a few pictures.

I have little to no knowledge of PHP and don't have the time to learn anything too advanced.

All replies would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi J.P Jack, and welcome to the Craft CMS Stack Exchange! I just re-tagged your question because we're phasing out [tag:learning-craft] to try to encourage the use of more specific tags instead. Please consider accepting Krzysztof's answer if it was helpful, and stop by the Craft Slack group if you haven't already. I'd be happy to chat on the subject, and it's a pretty friendly place in general.

Answer (score 2):

First of all to use Craft you need [a server and a database](https://craftcms.com/docs/requirements) - e.x. Apache and MySQL so it's not just PHP. Assuming you will get your hands on pre-installed craft instance basic [configuration](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings) is pretty straightforward. Also you need to understand craft concepts of [sections](https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries), [fields](https://craftcms.com/docs/fields), [relations](https://craftcms.com/docs/relations). Then you can setup blog or portfolio. Next you need to create views (TWIG language).

There are different plugins to help you with your content. Like this [one](https://github.com/70kft/craft-instablog) (blog). Installing plugin is as simple as copy folder and then hit install button in the CP.

Read [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17429/is-there-simpler-less-assuming-craft-documentation/17430#17430) where I included some resources to get you going with Craft.

Comment: In addition to this I would recommend the Video Course by Mijingo. I did this course and jumped right into Craft. https://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/up-and-running-with-craft/